# django user.is_authenticate dos not import

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am a beginner in Django and python and I Getting an error in Django login user in views.

I want to import user.is_authenticated in function in views.
Why user.is_authenticated dos not import and How can I resolve this Error?

Comment: please provide us the error you get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django if user.is\_authenticated not working but login user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72148465/django-if-user-is-authenticated-not-working-but-login-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a built-in decorator for that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
...
@login_required
def my_view(request):
...
```

That is for function defined views. For class based views you shold use the mixins:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
...
class my_view(LoginRequiredMixin, view):
...
```

user.is_autenticated is for use in templates:

```
{% if user.is_autenticated %}
```

Will allow you to conditionally display html in the template if the user is logged in. But don't relay just on this, you should do both (template & views) for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `request.user.is_authenticated` within a view function:

```
def  my_view(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         (Do something)
```